# How to use a retina image for Trigger.io setTitleImage in native topbar

Tags: ios, retina-display, trigger.io

I am trying to use the setTitleImage feature of trigger.io. I have an image that I saved @2x its original dimensions and am referencing it like so in the my main.js file:

```
forge.topbar.setTitleImage("img/logo@2x.png");
```

However, the image does not resize properly and I end up with a huge title image. Please advise on how to set a retina friendly title image in the native topbar.

Answer (score 0):

The image you set will be scaled to the exact height of the topbar if it is larger than it, you probably just need to include some transparent padding at the top and bottom of your image to scale it to the right size.